# psql command from official page on dockerhub

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerhub

I am learning Docker. I have practiced a lot, including testing commands from the official Postgres page on dockerhub.

I ran this command:

```
docker run -it --rm --network some-network postgres psql -h some-postgres -U postgres
```

Could someone give a complete and concrete example to make this command work (i mean with a real existing container). I can't see how it could work.

Answer (score 0):

`docker run` create a docker container
`-it` create a connection to said container (kinda like TTY) taking in what we write into interactive bash in the container
`--rm` delete the container when it exit
`--network some-network` assign `some-network` network to the container
`postgres` name of the image
`psql -h some-postgres -U postgres` connect to PostgreSQL at `some-postgres` address using `postgres` user.

Combine the entire command and flags: create a PostgreSQL container and the use the `psql` command from inside the container to connect to `some-postgres` using `postgres` user
For more flags and usage, you can learning from the doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, in the [Docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) is not perfectly clear but your command is used to connect to an already existing Postgres instance.

So, for example, you first create a container with the command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name postgresql -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin -d postgres:latest
```

then you can execute your command to connet to it

```
docker run -it --rm postgres psql -h <your_ip> -U postgres
```

If your container is running locally, you can get the ip from the bash command  `ip address`

The network attibute is related to the container you first startup so you can decide to leave or remove from the command in relation to the container deploy.